# Можно ли опустить «чем»?

Tags: союзы

> Список из более чем 20 пунктов.

Можно ли написать так: *Список из более 20 пунктов*?

Answer (score 3):

Допустимо: "Список из более чем 20 пунктов", "Список более чем из 20 пунктов".

В Вашем случае после слов «более чем» следует количественно-именное сочетание (счетный оборот). Не вижу необходимости опускать "чем". Сравните:
Таким образом тайна была сохранена **более чем** полудюжиною заговорщиков.  Егоров вообще не любил, когда начальник розыскного отдела отлучался **более чем на** сутки… Деревня была уже не **более чем в** двухстах шагах… Н. Гумилев.

Comment: *"Список из более чем 20 пунктов"* - Мне этот вариант совсем не нравится. А он по вашему мнению что-то значит иное, чем нормативный "более чем из"? Если да, то я смирюсь и с ним.

Comment: Вы, знаете, я с Вами полностью согласна. Мне тоже этот вариант не нравится, но когда писала ответ, заглянула на "Грамоту". Вот что нашла: "Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: более чем из(в) 100 стран(ах) - из(в) более чем 100 стран(ах)?" .
Ответ справочной службы русского языка:
"Предпочтителен второй вариант".

Comment: А можно ли разносить элементы выражения количества по обеим сторонам от предлога, указывающего на то, "из" чего состоит нечто в этом самом количестве? Из чего? Из пунктов. Из скольких? Из 20 пунктов. Если число не 20, а "более 20", то это другое число на том же естественном месте после предлога - такой вариант (из более чем 20) логичен: не "список более", а число "более 20". Альтернативному же варианту ещё нужно поискать оправдание.

Comment: @Alex_ander А, а вон Вы как трактуете... Логика есть, но не знаю, насколько это корректно.. Но возразить аргументированно не могу, Значит получается, что конструкция *"более чем двадцать"* является неким суррогатным числительным, которое может изменяться по падежам - в зависимости от требований управления, в т. ч. предложного... Похоже вы правы, грамматике не противоречит, чувство языка меня подвело.

Comment: *Ответ справочной службы русского языка: "Предпочтителен второй вариант"* - Ну со "Справкой" все понятно, они давно уже в какую-то угадайку играют - и иногда даже угадывают правильный ответ. А вот Alex_ander близок к тому, чтобы меня переубедить...)))

Answer (score 1):

А может просто "список, содержащий более 20-и пунктов"?

Comment: Так, значит можно?

Comment: Можно, но тут или "более чем двадцатЬ пунктов", либо "более двадцатИ пунктов".

Comment: Почему же не вписать это в Ответ? Он будет полным.